# What's the difference between a normal string and a string formatted by '%s'?

Tags: python

What's the difference between a normal string and a string formatted by '%s', because their results are different, like the following:

```
# It's ok
>>> "{%s}" % ' and '.join(['nice','good','perfect'])
'{nice and good and perfect}'

# It's not ok
>>> "{' and '}".join(['nice','good','perfect'])
"nice{' and '}good{' and '}perfect"
```

Comment: Have you actually thought through what each line of code *does*?

Answer (score 2):

Your first example,

```
"{%s}"%' and '.join(['nice','good','perfect'])
```

joins the list with the given string, `' and '` then puts that in place of the `%s`

Your second example,

```
"{' and '}".join(['nice','good','perfect'])
```

joins the list with the given string, `{' and '}`. So as you can see, these are two **completely** different operations, which is why you get a different output.

Comment: Thank you so much.The site is so useful that i have love it and you.The response is so fast. Please ignore an Chinese student's pool English.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code as

```
"{" + " and ".join(['nice','good','perfect']) + "}"
```

Output:

```
'{nice and good and perfect}'
```

Comment: think you very much,it's userful in this way.But i also want to know the defference.